# Give a collection B of subsets of R^2 that contains exactly 14 numbers of elements

Tags: general-topology

Give a collection $B$ of subsets of $\Bbb {R^2}$ that contains exactly 14 numbers of elements and $B$ forms a basis for some topology, say τB on $\Bbb {R^2}$. Show clearly that your collection $B$ forms a basis.

Comment: Hint: Here is a set of $4$ sets which forms a base for a topology on $\mathbb R^2$. The four sets are $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\lt2\}$, $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\lt3\}$, $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\lt5\}$, and $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Does "contains 14 numbers of elements" mean "contains 14 elements"???

Answer (score 1):

Take $13$ nested proper non-empty subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, say $A_1,\ldots, A_{13}$ where $i < j$ iff $A_i \subsetneq A_j$. And $\Bbb R^n$ itself and the properties of being a base for some topology are easily checked to be satisfied. The topology it generates has one more set, the empty set.